# Error when running any R code in R markdown

Tags: r, error-handling

```
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors ) invoking 'abort' restart
Error: option error has NULL value
```

whenever I try running any piece of code in R markdown. I didn't have any issues using R markdown last week. The only thing between then and now is that I ran a lot of data analysis on very large data frames(16M points) in another R script, which gave multiple warnings() which I ignored. Does that have anything to do with it? I quit Rstudio, tried restarting, tried clearing garbage with gc() but nothing works. Can't find much on this error on google.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the Markdown causing this problem?

Comment: there is none, literally any code that I try to run in r markdown

Comment: In such cases, the first thing I would do is to restart the PC

Comment: i already stated in post that i restarted. I just want to know what's causing it. is it a memory related error?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling R?